# Using Dapper with Oracle User-Defined Types

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, orm, dapper

Is there a way to use Dapper with Oracle User-Defined Types returned by stored procedures?
Dapper seems to work with stored procedures (see [Using Dapper with Oracle stored procedures which return cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390015/)).

```
var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
p.Add("param_list", null, OracleDbType.Object, ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("param_reco", null, OracleDbType.Object, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

In my example I've added a UDT collection object as output parameter (`param_list`).
I'm using the custom `OracleDynamicParameters` posted in [Dapper – Micro ORM for Oracle and Microsoft .NET](http://blog.vijay.name/index.php/2012/07/11/dapper-micro-orm-for-oracle-and-microsoft-net/).

The more I read ORM related stuff, the more I see Oracle UDT objects as an obstacle.
In this case plain ADO.NET and generated C# entity classes seem to be the only way to go.
Maybe [automapper.org](http://automapper.org/) might be useful for mapping domain objects to UDT objects.

Comment: what happens currently? does it error? or just not update the out parameters? or...?

Comment: Each `Query` call produces an `ArgumentException` (ODAC set_value). But this may be caused by the classic ODAC assemply used. I've replaced the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` with the classic ODP.NET's `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`. The managed ODP driver is still beta.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using OracleCustomTypeMapping attribute and the OracleObjectMapping attribute. Can't recall where I got this idea from but...

```
public interface INullableOracleCustomType: INullable,  IOracleCustomType
    {
    }

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("<YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME>.<UDT_OBJECT_NAME>")]
    public class ParameterObject : INullableOracleCustomType
    {
        private bool objectIsNull;

        #region constructor

        public ParameterObject()
        { }

        public ParameterObject(string parameterName, string parameterValue)
        {
            this.ParameterName = parameterName;
            this.ParameterValue = parameterValue;
        }

        #endregion

        #region properties
        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("PARAMETERNAME")]
        public string ParameterName { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("PARAMETERVALUE")]
        public string ParameterValue { get; set; }

        public static ParameterObject Null
        {
            get
            {
                ParameterObject parameterObject = new ParameterObject();
                parameterObject.objectIsNull = true;
                return parameterObject;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region INullable Members

        public bool IsNull
        {
            get { return objectIsNull; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IOracleCustomType
        public void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            // Convert from the Custom Type to Oracle Object
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParameterName))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PARAMETERNAME", ParameterName);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParameterValue))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "PARAMETERVALUE", ParameterValue);
            }
        }

        public void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            ParameterName = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PARAMETERNAME");
            ParameterValue = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "PARAMETERVALUE");
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

example usage ...

```
public static OracleParameter CreateCustomTypeArrayInputParameter<T>(string name, string oracleUDTName, T value)
            where T : INullableOracleCustomType
        {
            OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = name;
            parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parameter.UdtTypeName = oracleUDTName;
            parameter.Value = value;
            return parameter;
        }
```

Oracle seems fussy about the schema/type/object names being in ALLCAPS

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but I hope this can be answered :
In case we don't want an array, but just a custom udt return parameter, (for exemple), chat would be the OracleDbType ?

Comment: For documentation on the OracleDbType enumeration, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm#ODPNT2286