# Oracle error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures, dapper, odp.net

I'm using Dapper and ODP.Net to call a stored procedure.
I feel dumb not to find what's wrong with my parameters but here it goes:

Here is the stored procedure signature:

```
PROCEDURE SP_NETWORK_GETALL(UserLogon IN VARCHAR2, NetworkVersionList OUT refCursor)
```

And here is my .Net call:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    var parameters = new List<OracleParameter>
    {
        new OracleParameter()
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            ParameterName = "UserLogon",
            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2,
            Size = 4000,
            Value = "TEST"
        },
        new OracleParameter()
        {
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
            OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
            ParameterName = "NetworkVersionList",
            Value = DBNull.Value
        },
    };

    var results = conn.Query("SDTM.PKG_SP_GET.SP_NETWORK_GETALL", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

I've tried this stored procedure, it works. I have used Dapper for other stored procedures, it works as well. I have tried changing the order of the parameters (the ref cursor first), setting the size of the VarChar2 parameter or not, DBNull.Value for the ref cursor or not.

I have seen a million questions like this one on stackoverflow or on internet, but I can't see the parameter mismatch here...

Comment: Is the schema name required?

Comment: Well I just tried without the schema name and I get the same error, so I don't think this is the issue...

Comment: The usual cause of this error is because ODP.NET by default binds by position, not by parameter name. That does not seem to be the problem here, but just in case the procedure you provided us is not the actual one, make sure you bind in the correct order or set Bindbyname to true. Next, make sure "refcursor" is an oracle type. I though the correct type was SYS_Refcursor. If it is actually a user defined type, and not a simple ref_cursor you cannot bind like this. Maybe you should provide us the actual create statement for the procedure.

Comment: This article is old, but you should have a look and see what you are doing differently. Since you have a helper class to bind and execute it is hard to say where you are going wrong: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/williams-refcursors-092375.html

Comment: Well I managed to do something that worked. I created a class that implements SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters as suggested by this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390015/using-dapper-with-oracle-stored-procedures-which-return-cursors). It adds the parameters just before the command is executed. I did not change the parameters declaration and it works... I smell something fishy in ODP.Net here. I leave the question open if somebody has a better solution... Thanks anyway Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a list of OracleParameter objects to dapper's "parameters" variable.  Dapper is meant to be provider agnostic and you're sending provider specific types.

Take a look at the GetCacheInfo method in the dapper code and you'll see three cases in the way that dapper attempts to handle parameters:

1. An object of IDynamicParameters
2. An object of IEnumerable< KeyValuePair< string, object>>
3. Default/Else - Attempt to find properties in your object that match the tokens in the command.

You're probably falling into the default case, yet because you have a proc, there are no tokens in the command and no parameters are added.  Even if they were, it would probably be searching thru the properties of type List<> and it's not going to find a match.

Adding IDynamicParameters puts you in control of the parameters and that's why it works.  This has nothing to do with odp.net.

I suppose this is one of my irks with dapper as with all ORMs - as hard as they will try, there's always going going to be provider specific stuff that can't be abstracted away.  That's why I prefer to simply setup the provider specific command and then use a utility class that ONLY does the mapping (without concerning itself with the connection/setup/execution).

Comment: So my class that implements SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters was the way to go. What seems strange then is that I used dapper before with other stored procedure (with refCursors, UDT and other oracle specifics stuff) by sending directly a list of OracleParameters and it was working fine.

Comment: I guess I'd be interested to see a case that does work like you describe.  Maybe even debug into the dapper code and see how the params are being added.  Maybe there's a branch that i'm not seeing.