# Multiple Result Sets with Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

Simple Question:

My code looks like this:

```
        var con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.20.10.8)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl12c)));");
        con.Open();

        var adp = new OracleDataAdapter("select * from adr;select * from person;", con);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
```

Now I would expect to get two tables in the DataSet, but I rather get an exception telling me that the SQL Syntax is not correct... It seems the ; is not recognized that way..? Any Ideas?

Edit #1: **Also Adding *BEGIN+END;* does not work (multiple variations)**

Edit #2: *Wrapping the selects with **execute immediate** will run, but won't return a result set.*

**Solution**: Combine the provided answer with [Using Dapper with Oracle stored procedures which return cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390015/using-dapper-with-oracle-stored-procedures-which-return-cursors) and enjoy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute multiple queries in single Oracle command in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917301/execute-multiple-queries-in-single-oracle-command-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Run one query at a time and omit the semicolon, or put both queries in a PL/SQL block https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262145/ora-00911-invalid-character

Comment: Not a duplicate and putting it in one block does not resolve the question, but digs for another solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write an anonymous `pl/sql` block that returns `ref cursors`.

Try this in `ADO.NET`:

```
    oraConnection = new OracleConnection();
    da = new OracleDataAdapter();
    ds = new DataSet();

    oraConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.20.10.8)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl12c)));";
    cmdText = "begin open :1 for select * from adr; open :2 for select * from person; end;"; 
    cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
    cmd.Connection = oraConnection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 

    OracleParameter refcur1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Refcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
    refcur1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    OracleParameter refcur2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("Refcur", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
    refcur2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: As said, it is oracle related. @HasanFathi your answer works, but I was hoping for a solution with pure SQL so I wouldn't need to handle parameters. Why? Because I would like to use Dapper, which works with pure string statements and connections.

Comment: @Jaster my solution for `ADO.NET`, in `Dapper.NET` you can use `QueryMultiple`.

Comment: @Jaster in `ADO.NEt` you should use my suggested approach

Comment: @Jaster you wanted functionality not handled through pure sql , you want a solution for get multiple result that return from sql that related to dapper or ado

Comment: No worries, I'll accept the answer... QueryMultiple will not work as it only accepts a string, not a command...